# How can I restrict access to HR data in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

We have a SQL Server database with an HR schema that contains human resources data. It includes salary and other private information. Database owners, sysadmins, and members of an [Executives] role are allowed to see the HR schema.

Some of the other users are members of the db_datareader role which has the ability to read the data from any table of the database. They were added to the role before the HR security requirement existed.

What is a strategy to deny access to all other users?

Comment: Some of the other users are members of the db_datareader role which has the ability to read the data from any table of the database. They were added to the role before the HR security requirement existed.

Comment: You can DENY on the HR schema to those users directly. Or create a role and add users to that role and deny for the role.

Comment: @Tarzan, I edited your question to include the relevant info from your comment. Personally, I avoid using built-in database roles unless the db is dedicated to a specific application or group of users. The DENY approach Tibor suggested is probably the easiest way to accomplish this. Another method is a custom role like `limited_db_datareader` granted `SELECT` on all schemas except HR.

Comment: Another option to consider is column masking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing you have to do is to remove other users from `db_datareader` role

```
alter role db_datareader drop member user1
alter role db_datareader drop member user2
```

Then create custom database role, like `other_users`, you name it, add members:

```
alter role [other_users] add member user1
alter role [other_users] add member user2
```

then grant select on database to role

```
grant select to [other_users]
```

Then deny access to HR schema to `other_users`

```
deny select on schema::HR to [other_users]
```

This way you will have other users be able to read from any other schema or table, except HR schema

Comment: Members of db_datareader will not be able to read if there is an active DENY.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft you are right, edited my answer and removed that false statement. Maybe it was true for older SQL Server versions ?  Anyway, removed that part. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @AlekseyVitsko, I believe DENY has always taken precedence over GRANT, at least going back to SQL Server 4.21a ca 1993.

Comment: From memory, DENY was introduced in 7.0 ("the new architecture"), and it has been working the same way since. Prior to 7.0, we only had GRANT and REVOKE and end result was dependent on what order you executed the those statements in (nightmare). Again, this is from memory, and it has been a while since those days. :-)

Comment: @DanGuzman DENY > GRANT always, that is correct - but something made me think db_datareader > DENY. I believe one of questions in certification exam was stating that and I was under impression that I even tested that out back then. Anyway, as we see that is not true :)  so I removed that line from the answer

Comment: @TiborKaraszi, you may be right. I also remember the GRANT/REVOKE order consideration from trailing back then. All that is ancient history I should know better than to trust my memory nowadays anyway.